# How can I change date to swedish time zone in a Perl script?

Tags: perl

How can I convert a date in format '20170119121941Z' to Swedish time zone in a Perl script?

My current snippet is:

```
sub get_Date {

my $content = shift;

my $iso8601 = DateTime::Format::ISO8601 -> new;
my $dt = $iso8601->parse_datetime( $content );
###Set the time zone to "Europe/Stockholm" .
$dt->set_time_zone("Europe/Stockholm");
my $dayofmonth = $dt->strftime("%d");
$dayofmonth =~ s/^0//;
my $hour = $dt->strftime("%I");
$hour =~ s/^0//;
my $ISODate = $dt->strftime("%b " . $dayofmonth . ", %Y, " . $hour . ":%M %p ", localtime(time));
return($ISODate);

}
```

Comment: Your code contradicts your question.

Answer (score 4):

The output you are getting is

```
Invalid date format: 20170119121941Z
```

Your code is failing with that message because `20170119121941Z` doesn't match a valid ISO8601 format.

There's also the issue that you used `strftime` correctly twice, then did something nonsense for the third use.

Solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say state );

use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

sub localize_dt_str {
   my ($dt_str) = @_;

   state $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
      pattern  => '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%Z',
      on_error => 'croak',
   );

   my $dt = $format->parse_datetime($dt_str);
   $dt->set_time_zone('Europe/Stockholm');
   return $dt->strftime('%b %e, %Y, %l:%M %p');
}

say localize_dt_str('20170119121941Z');   # Jan 19, 2017,  1:19 PM
```